# Find members and members of sub-group

Tags: asp.net, active-directory, ldap, directoryservices, directorysearcher

How do I get a list of all the **members** AND (members of the) **subgroups** within a specific group/department using DirectorySearcher and Filter/PropertiesToLoad?

At the moment, I can get the group to return all its members. However, there are sub-groups within the group and I cannot get to the members within those sub-groups too.

This is what I have so far:

```
        DirectoryEntry entry = null;
    entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://DC=au,DC=company,DC=com", null, null, AuthenticationTypes.Secure);

    try
    {
        DirectorySearcher ouSearch = new DirectorySearcher(entry);
        ouSearch.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(displayName=*" + username + "*)" +
        "(|" +
            "(memberOf=CN=my department,OU=ADC-Distribution Groups,DC=au,DC=company,DC=com)" +

        ")" +

        ")";

        ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("samAccountName");
        ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");
        ouSearch.PropertiesToLoad.Add("memberOf");
        ouSearch.SearchScope = SearchScope.Subtree;

        SearchResultCollection allOUS = ouSearch.FindAll();
```

Any assistance appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to do the search recursively expanding every subgroup that is a member of another group.

However, there is a lot easier method using the [`GroupPrincipal`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.groupprincipal.members.aspx) class of the System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement namespace.

`GroupPrincipal` has a method [`GetMembers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb339975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which allows you to retrieve all members of a group recursively.  All you have to do is specify `true` as the only parameter to GetMembers.

The following example is copied from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb339975%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,                                                                    
                                        "fabrikam.com", 
                                        "DC=fabrikam,DC=com", 
                                        "administrator", 
                                        "SecretPwd123");

GroupPrincipal grp = GroupPrincipal.FindByIdentity(ctx, 
                                               IdentityType.Name, 
                                               "Domain Admins");

if (grp != null)
{
    foreach (Principal p in grp.GetMembers(recursive: true))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(p.Name);
    }
    grp.Dispose();
}

ctx.Dispose();
```

Comment: Thank you so much Jakob....I've been looking for a solution for days and this is exactly what I'm after. Much appreciated your response!

Comment: Do you know if there's some name filtering i can use for GroupPrincipal class? My getMembers() returns over 1k members and it is taking a long time - i need to loop through each members and check if their names matches a certain pattern. Atm, it's taking a good 10 seconds to loop through each!

Comment: @viv_acious: I don't think you can filter this way. But why not perform a search for the users using PrincipalSearcher instead of using GetMembers?